# getting syntax when creating table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a mySQL table with php and I am getting a syntax error whenever I run my code. The string is

```
$sql = "DROP TABLE Colors;
CREATE TABLE Colors (
color VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
vote INT(16) NOT NULL UNSIGNED,
hex VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (color)
)";
```

query line is ($conn is the connection to the server)

```
$conn->query($sql)
```

The error is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'CREATE TABLE Colors (
color VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
vote INT(16) NOT NULL UNSIGNED' at line 2
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried adding `IF EXISTS` to the end of the drop statement

Comment: You cant execute 2 queries with `query`. Also `int(16)` is not possible, you'll need `bigint`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html Note the `Maximum Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which mysql lib you are using, but in PHP you should use function [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) in your scenario.

```
$sql = "DROP TABLE Colors;
        CREATE TABLE Colors (
        color VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        vote INT(16) NOT NULL UNSIGNED,
        hex VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (color)
)";

mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: I missed the multi_query part when I was trying to figure that out. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Getting into the habit of using `multi_query` is really a bad thing. Each statement might produce an error and knowing which statement produced it is very important. That the function even exists seems like a serious lapse of judgement on the part of the library designers.

Comment: Well, that depends. For most users this could be important, but in some scenarios that function would be better.

Answer (score 4):

You need to execute one statement at a time. `;` is a construct used by the command-line tool as a delimiter, it's not actually used in the MySQL protocol for communicating so it's an error. The `DELIMITER` value can also be changed.

Split up it looks like this:

```
$conn->query("DROP TABLE Colors");
$conn->query("CREATE TABLE ...");
```

Note, I **strongly** encourage you to do proper error checking here and have exceptions turned on so that if a statement fails you know about it.

Comment: I do have error checking but I didn't put it in my question. Also I was under the impression that you could put multiple queries together using `;`

Comment: @SirParselot Usually not the case. That is usually disable to avoid the damage a SQL injection can do. We don't know what `$conn` is or which `query()` you are using.